# Proposition of complexes in Homology

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I have been reading Maclane's book on Homology and he talks about the following proposition :

> "When the ring $R$ is regarded as a trivial complex then $Hom(R,L) \cong L$, under the natural homomorphism wich assigns to each $f_p: R \rightarrow L_p$ its image $f_p(1) \in L_p$."

I have two questions that are,

1) What does he mean by a trivial complex ?

2)This isomorphism is in the context of the category?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The trivial complex is the complex that has $R$ in degree $0$ and has $0$ in all other degrees. (2) It's an isomorphism of complexes of $R$-modules.

Comment: Alright thanks , how do we define the isomorphism of complexes, is it an isomorphism in every degree or do we use a category ? ( wich they probably are equivalent)

Comment: An isomorphism of complexes consists of isomorphisms in all degrees, commuting with the morphisms in the complexes. To make it look more category-theoretic: Complexes of modules are the objects of a category, in which a morphism consists of morphisms in all degrees commuting with the morphisms in the complexes.  Isomorphisms of complexes are exactly the isomorphisms (i.e., the invertible morphisms) in this category.